# Generate Text File With Only 7th and 8th Columns From Given ls Command Output

Tags: text-processing, awk

Here follows given `ls` output:

```
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  300488 2019-10-11 21:29 1570840157.M399816P376041.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=300488,W=304621:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  307582 2019-10-11 21:30 1570840228.M85932P379995.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=307582,W=311813:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  301166 2019-10-11 21:31 1570840312.M211863P379995.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=301166,W=305309:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  308153 2019-10-11 21:32 1570840376.M535629P379995.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=308153,W=312391:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  307387 2019-10-11 21:34 1570840441.M68421P382468.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=307387,W=311615:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  298927 2019-10-11 21:35 1570840530.M391347P385138.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=298927,W=303039:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  302107 2019-10-11 21:36 1570840597.M688174P387663.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=302107,W=306263:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  299284 2019-10-11 21:37 1570840657.M991954P387663.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=299284,W=303401:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  299941 2019-10-11 21:39 1570840743.M587693P390982.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=299941,W=304067:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  305586 2019-10-11 21:40 1570840805.M471644P390982.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=305586,W=309789:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  302585 2019-10-11 21:41 1570840869.M734632P390982.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=302585,W=306747:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  300967 2019-10-11 21:42 1570840929.M49892P396393.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=300967,W=305107:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  309171 2019-10-11 21:43 1570840996.M935135P396393.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=309171,W=313423:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  306032 2019-10-11 21:44 1570841063.M337072P398299.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=306032,W=310241:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  307273 2019-10-11 21:45 1570841123.M319021P399614.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=307273,W=311499:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  300586 2019-10-11 21:46 1570841190.M781954P399602.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=300586,W=304721:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  299949 2019-10-11 21:47 1570841258.M111576P402416.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=299949,W=304075:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  305696 2019-10-11 21:48 1570841322.M811059P402416.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=305696,W=309901:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  298530 2019-10-11 21:49 1570841388.M749590P402416.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=298530,W=302637:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  295861 2019-10-11 21:50 1570841452.M450157P402416.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=295861,W=299931:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  299296 2019-10-11 21:51 1570841517.M363735P407440.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=299296,W=303413:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  298266 2019-10-11 21:53 1570841581.M704762P407486.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=298266,W=302369:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  294032 2019-10-11 21:54 1570841642.M46478P407486.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=294032,W=298077:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  300326 2019-10-11 21:55 1570841706.M4802P410758.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=300326,W=304457:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  308640 2019-10-11 21:56 1570841769.M154215P410758.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=308640,W=312885:2,
-rw-r----- 1 ronald ronald  313215 2019-10-11 21:57 1570841839.M665145P410758.br472.hostgator.com.br,S=313215,W=317523:2,
```

What is needed is a text file extracted from this list with only 7th and 8th columns of it.

How could this be done?

Comment: [Don't Parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).   Instead, use `stat` with `--format` or `--printf` options (GNU stat) or `-f` (BSD stat).   That will let you print whichever file metadata you want, in any format you want.    `find`'s `-printf` option is another good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this is already a duplicate but:

```
ls [OPTIONS] | awk '{print $7,$8}' >file.txt
```

Also you probably [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

(if one of your filenames had a space in it, it would actually become two separate columns as far as `awk` is concerned)

Comment: Made some reading here about `ls` parsing, but may you explain clearly why `ls` command shouldn't be parsed?